# SQL data update query

Tags: sql

I have an SQL data table with the date stored in date format in one column as yyyy-mm-dd. I have created a new column with bigint and want to write a query to convert the date to bigint and update my new column. I tried using CAST and received a message that I cannot explicitly convert date to bigint. Could someone help me with an SQL formula to convert date (yyyy-mm-dd) to bigint

Comment: What is the numeric target format you're expecting? Something like `yyyymmdd` or something different? Perhaps a unix timestamp?

Comment: Please Update your Question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which brand of SQL server you are using, but on Microsoft SQL Server you can use the convert function to achieve this.

(edit) Added an example based on the information from the comments. I'm still assuming you are using SQL server:

If your table has a datetime column called 'IssueDate' and a new bigint column called IssueDateOAD, you can run this query:

`update mytable set IssueDateOAD = convert(bigint, IssueDate) + 2`

If IssueDate is a varchar column containing a date-formatted string you must convert it to a date first. For yyyy-mm-dd you can use `convert(datetime, IssueDate, 126)` (see the documentation for the style codes you can pass to convert, 126 means we're passing a ISO8601-formatted date)

The query including conversion from varchar to datetime is:

`update mytable set IssueDateOAD = convert(bigint, convert(datetime, IssueDate, 126)) + 2`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I want to convert to OADate format. I have tried the CONVERT without much luck, do you have an example

Comment: SQL server starts at 1900-01-01 00:00, and OAdate starts at 1899-12-30 00:00, so select convert(bigint, getdate()) - 2 should do?

Comment: *plus* 2, not minus. Noticed it too late to edit my own comment.

Comment: I put convert(bigint,expression,getdate())-2  but it still gives the same message as above